# The current element as its Event function param

Tags: javascript, dom

I've got an element

```
<input type="text">
```

On this, there is an Event

```
onChange="myfunction(param)".
```

"param" is the content of the input itself. How can I handle, that, when I fire onChange (so complete the change of the field), in this param is the actual value of this field?

Is it possible to do something like that:

```
onChange="myfunction(document.getElementById('this_id'))"
```

Comment: You can use `onchange="myfunction.call(this)"` as from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12812974/1720476 Where "this" will be pointing to current object, and you can get params then as you wish with `this.` heyword in a called function..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can pass `this` to `myFunction` which will be the `input`

```
<input type="text" onChange="myfunction(this)" />
```

then `myFunction` could look like this:

```
function myFunction(obj)
{
    var value = obj.value; // the value of the textbox
}
```

Comment: OK thanx ;) I forgot that "this" is existing ;) Thank you very much

Comment: `myfunction` vs `myFunction` ?

Answer (score 4):

Inside an inline event handler, `this` will refer to the DOM element.

Therefore, you can write `onchange="myfunction(this)"` to pass the DOM element itself to the function.

Answer (score 2):

To get the [`.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input) inline, it would look like this:

```
<input type="text" onchange="myfunction(this.value)" />
```