# Passing 'this' to an onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The current element as its Event function param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268085/the-current-element-as-its-event-function-param)

Would this work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo = function(param)
{
    param.innerHTML = "Not a button";
};
</script>
<button onclick="foo(this)" id="bar">Button</button>
```

rather than this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo = function()
{
    document.getElementId("bar").innerHTML = "Not a button";
};
</script>
<button onclick="foo()" id="bar">Button</button>
```

And would the first method allow me to load the javascript from elsewhere to perform actions on any page element?

Comment: It makes not much sense to ask if something *would* work. Better test your own and also clarify on the commands you want to make use of and you're unsure with.

Comment: (Short but complete) answer: **YES**

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The code that you have would work, but is executed from the global context, which means that `this` refers to the global object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo = function(param) {
    param.innerHTML = "Not a button";
};
</script>
<button onclick="foo(this)" id="bar">Button</button>
```

You can also use the non-inline alternative, which attached to and executed from the specific element context which allows you to access the element from `this`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('bar').onclick = function() {
    this.innerHTML = "Not a button";
};
</script>
<button id="bar">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 23):

You can always call funciton differently: `foo.call(this);` in this way you will be able to use `this` context inside the function.

Example:

`<button onclick="foo.call(this)" id="bar">Button</button>​`

```
var foo = function()
{
    this.innerHTML = "Not a button";
};
```

Comment: Great! Is there any drawback for this?

Answer (score 6):

Yeah first method will work on any element called from elsewhere since it will always take the
target element irrespective of id.

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8cvBM/

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript **`this`** always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of. When we define our faithful function doSomething() in a page, its owner is the page, or rather, the window object (or global object) of JavaScript.

[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: `this` is the object from which the function is called at call-time. There is no notion of "owner" in javascript. If the function is called without the use of an object, then `this` is the global object (`window` in a browser). For instance: `function f(){ console.log(this); }; o={a:f}; o.a(); var b = o.a; b();`