# JavaScript this and onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I thought that JavaScript is simple, but seems that it doesn't work

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function org(){
    $(this).toggle()
}
</script>
<span onClick="org()" id="kaka">Click me and i hide</span>
```

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: Yes - what is $(this)?

Comment: Why not use a jQuery event handler, that way this isn't an issue at all

Comment: Took a while but found it, Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268085/the-current-element-as-its-event-function-param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass a reference to the element. You can also tell the function to use the element for `this`

```
<span onClick="org.call(this);" id="kaka">Click me and i hide</span>
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rGw5/3/)

Comment: Sorry for the wait, but this seems to work best for my situation

Answer (score 7):

`this` in your code is not referencing your `<span>` element. You need to pass a reference to your element.

```
<script>
function org(e){
    $(e).toggle()
}
</script>
<span onClick="org(this)" id="kaka">Click me and i hide</span>
```

Alternatively (and this is really the preferred way) you can attach an event handler and avoid using an inline handler:

```
<script>
$("kaka").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggle()
});
</script>
<span id="kaka">Click me and i hide</span>
```

Comment: Just saying for such a simple answer for a question that is asked here like everyday. It's  not like this answer is innovative.

Comment: @RPM If that's the case, you should close the question instead of answering it ;) Don't you have the rep? (I think it's 2000 but i'm not sure)

Comment: I don't care that much. I just don't see this answer as being that valuable. It probably is for the beginners.