# Simple javascript click to add class not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add / remove a class on an element that is clicked liek this

```js
function myFunction() {
    this.classList.add("myclass");
}
```

```css
#first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.myclass {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" onclick="myFunction(this)">

  Click
  
  <div class="second">
  </div>
  
  <div class="third">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The current element as its Event function param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268085/the-current-element-as-its-event-function-param)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass reference `this` into function too like:

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  el.classList.add("myclass");
}
```

```css
#first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.myclass {
  background: red!important;
  color: white!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" onclick="myFunction(this)">

  Click

  <div class="second">
  </div>

  <div class="third">
  </div>

</div>
```

PS. add `!important` into css

Comment: Don't recommend `!important`, rather define the css to have appropriate [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). (if you need !important with only two styles defined imagine a full stylesheet).

Comment: I didn't recommend it, I just fixed the JS problem and added a quick CSS rule to show the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `this` to the defined function too and check the existence of the class. Try this.

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  if(!el.classList.contains("myclass")) {
    el.classList.add("myclass");
    console.log("added");
  } else {
    el.classList.remove("myclass");
    console.log("removed");
  }
}
```

```css
#first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.myclass {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" onclick="myFunction(this)">

  Click
  
  <div class="second">
  </div>
  
  <div class="third">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `this` for inline handlers works differently. You can use `.call`, and that works... but that's still not good.

```js
function myFunction() {
  this.classList.add("myclass");
}
```

```css
#first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.myclass {
  background: red !important;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" onclick="myFunction.call(this)">
  Click
  <div class="second">
  </div>
  <div class="third">
  </div>
</div>
```

You should avoid inline script altogether and also avoid id selectors in CSS.

[Change your id selector to a class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and change your inline handler to an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Also, stray strings like "content" are a real pain as your project grows in size. Wrap them in a `<span>`

```js
const myButton = document.querySelector(".first");

myButton.addEventListener("click", ({
  target
}) => target.classList.add("myclass"))
```

```css
.first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.myclass {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <span>Click</span>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing 2 issues :

- you pass `this` as a parameter to the `onclick` event, but don't get it in the function definition `()`, so you can fix it like below ;
- id selector is more specific than class selector, so it always take precedence. You can use a class instead of an id for first div, and then your css rule works :)

```js
function myFunction(el) {
    el.classList.add("myclass");
}
```

```css
.first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.myclass {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="first" onclick="myFunction(this);">

  Click
  
  <div class="second">
  </div>
  
  <div class="third">
  </div>
  
</div>
```